How to mock a function in a django custom command?
How can I mock foo in order to have it NOT called?
Here's my latest attempt:
#~/django/myapp/management/commands/acme.py
def foo():
    pass
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
       foo()

#~/django/myapp/tests/test.py
from django.core.management import call_command
@mock.patch('myapp.management.commands.acme.foo')
def test_command_output(self,mock_foo):
    call_command('acme')
    assert not mock_foo.called


You are already mocking foo. The call to foo is now intercepted by the mock (the logic in foo won't be executed). mock_foo.called returns True because the mock records any calls to the object it is mocking.
If this isn't helpful it might be worth trying to explain what you exactly are trying to achieve here.
